# Efficient bookkeeping in heap

Tags: python, heap

I'm trying to implement a heap using list data structure. I'd also like to keep track of the position of elements in the list in order to enable easy deletion. My implementation involves looping through the entire list to update the positions after an insert/delete combo. I'm afraid this raises the time complexity from O(log n) to O(n). 
Is there a better way of keeping track of elements' position? Currently, update method is what takes care of the bookkeeping.

```
class heap():
    ''' Min-Heap'''
    def __init__(self,G):
        self.list=[0] #to ease dealing with indices, an arbitrary value at index 0
        self.pos={} #holds position of elements with respect to list
        self.G = G #Graph, contains the score for each element in G[element][2]

    def update_pos(self):
        self.pos = {}
        for i in xrange(1,len(self.list)):
            self.pos[self.list[i]]=i

    def percUp(self): #percolate up, called by insert method
        start = len(self.list)-1
        while start//2>0:
            if self.G[self.list[start/2]][2] > self.G[self.list[start]][2]:
                self.list[start/2],self.list[start] = self.list[start],self.list[start/2]
            start = start//2

    def insert(self,element):
        self.list.append(element)
        self.percUp()
        self.update_pos()

    def percDown(self,start=1): #percolate down, called by extract_min method
        while 2*start < len(self.list):
            min_ind = self.getMinInd(start)
            if self.G[self.list[start]][2] > self.G[self.list[min_ind]][2]:
                self.list[start],self.list[min_ind] = self.list[min_ind],self.list[start]
            start = min_ind

    def extract_min(self):
        self.list[-1],self.list[1] = self.list[1],self.list[-1]
        small = self.list[-1]
        self.list = self.list[:-1]
        self.percDown()
        self.update_pos()
        return small

    def delete(self,pos):
        self.list[-1],self.list[pos] = self.list[pos],self.list[-1]
        self.pos.pop(self.list[pos])
        self.list = self.list[:-1]
        self.percDown(pos)
        self.update_pos()

    def getMinInd(self,start):
        if 2*start+1 > len(self.list)-1:
            return 2*start
        else:
            if self.G[self.list[2*start]][2]<self.G[self.list[2*start+1]][2]:
                return 2*start
            else:
                return 2*start+1
```

Comment: I think your question is a better fit for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building a binary heap, the best way I know of to speed up arbitrary removal or changing priority is to create a hash map. The key is the item in the priority queue, and the value is its current position in the array. When you insert an item into the queue, you add an entry to the hash map with the item's current position.

Then, *every time* an item is moved in the queue, you update its value in the hash map. So every time you do a swap during insertion or removal, you update the swapped items' values in that hash map.

To remove an arbitrary item, then, you do the following:

1. Look up the item's position in the hash map.
2. Delete the item's entry in the hash map.
3. Move the last item in the heap to the removed item's position, and update its position in the hash map.
4. Sift the new item up or down in the heap, as required, updating all affected nodes' positions in the hash map.

This works reasonably well, although it can be pretty expensive in terms of memory if your heap is large.

Other heap data structures such as Fibonacci heap, Pairing heap, Skew heap, or even a binary heap implemented as a binary tree work with individual heap nodes rather than implicit nodes in an array, and therefore can be accessed directly without the need of an intermediate hash table. They do require more memory than a binary heap implemented as an array, but are potentially much more efficient.

By the way, if you decide to experiment with one of those alternate structures, I'd recommend that you take a look at Pairing heap. Its asymptotic performance is almost as good as Fibonacci heap, and it's *much* easier to implement. I don't yet have any good numbers on its real-world performance.